# mongoDB records without ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

When I'm using `mongoDB` native driver to interact in my `NodeJS` app, I'm surprised by seeing few records in a particular collection. Following is output of my `find()` query.

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa14080f375c27bb8378076"),
    "first_name" : "Smith",
    "last_name" : "James",
    "email" : "Smith.James@gmail.com",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "hobbies" : {
        "indoor_games" : true,
        "outdoor_games" : true,
        "other" : false
    },
    "profession" : "Employee",
    "notifications" : true
}
{
    "_id" : "5aa14034394a267adb8e42f7",  --> here without ObjectId
    "first_name" : "Davis",
    "last_name" : "John",
    "email" : "Davis.John@gmail.com",
    "gender" : "Male",
    "hobbies" : {
        "indoor_games" : true,
        "outdoor_games" : true,
        "other" : false
    },
    "profession" : "Employee",
    "notifications" : true
}
```

As of I'm aware of `_id` is generated by `mongo` itself but for few records why there is no `ObjectId` instead only an alphanumeric string exists? Is there any reason behind this? All records are saved using `mongoDB` native driver package for `Nodejs`.

Comment: Does your application insert _id explicitly?

Comment: As of I remembered, I haven't inserted manually from `mongo console` all records are inserted using `nodejs` app and in insert statement also I haven't used `_id`.

Comment: use  $type and verfiy the type of _id

Answer (score 1):

This will happen only if you will insert objectId intentionally or manually. At the time of save/insert MongoDB creates it's "_id" as ObjectId itself.